# Binomial theorem question. Find the value of the constant $k$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

$$\left[(k+x)\left(2-\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]^6$$

where the coefficient of $x^{2}$ is $84$.Find the value of the constant $k$.
I tried to expand the equation but got a equation of degree 6 for some reason.

Comment: By multiplying the two binomials we get: $$\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\left(2-\frac k 2\right)x+2k\right)^6$$ Here, we have three terms with different exponents of $x$, so we need to use the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: Let say I haven't learn multinomial theorem yet...is there another way?My teacher says it's out of sysbullus and I can't use it.

Comment: Yes, there is another way, but it's kind of hard to explain. I am writing an answer about it right now.

Comment: Expanding both binomials or using $a_2=f''(0)/2$ gives the same 6th degree equation in $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By multiplying the two binomials inside the parentheses, we get:
$$\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\left(2-\frac k 2\right)x+2k\right)^6$$
Here, we can't use the binomial theorem since this is a trinomial. Instead, we need to get creative.

When you think about it, there are two ways to get $x^2$:

- Five of the terms we multiply are $2k$ and one of them is $-\frac{x^2}{2}$. There are $\frac{6!}{5!1!}=6$ ways to do this.
- Four of the terms we multiply are $2k$ and two of them are $\left(2-\frac k 2\right)x$. There are $\frac{6!}{4!2!}=15$ ways to do this.

Thus, the $x^2$ term of this expansion must be:
$$6\cdot(2k)^5\frac{-x^2}{2}+15(2k)^4\left(\left(2-\frac k 2\right)x\right)^2=-96k^5x^2+(60k^6-480k^5+960k^4)x^2=(60k^6-576k^5+960k^4)x^2$$

Now, you said the coefficient of $x^2$ is $84$, so we get:
$$60k^6-576k^5+960k^4=84$$
There's no way we're solving this by hand. According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=60*k%5E6-576*k%5E5%2B960*k%5E4%3D84), we get the real solutions of:
$$x \approx -0.50361$$
$$x \approx 0.603321$$
$$x \approx 2.13401$$
$$x \approx 7.45339$$
Since this is a polynomial of sixth degree, it's likely that solving this polynomial using just radicals is actually impossible, so there's no way I can give you an exact answer. However, I have checked all of these and they are correct because they all give us a coefficient of $x^2$ that is very close to $84$ when typed into Wolfram Alpha.

- [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%28%28-.507361%2Bx%29%282-x%2F2%29%29%5E6) is the check for the first solution.
- [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%28%280.603231%2Bx%29%282-x%2F2%29%29%5E6) is the check for the second solution.
- [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%28%282.13401%2Bx%29%282-x%2F2%29%29%5E6) is the check for the third solution.
- [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%28%287.45339%2Bx%29%282-x%2F2%29%29%5E6) is the check for the fourth solution.

Comment: What is radicals?so there's a way to solve an equation of degree 6 using radicals?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi Radicals are like square roots. For example the solutions to the equation $x^2=2$ are expressed as $\pm \sqrt 2$. However, there are polynomial equations of degree $5$ and above like this one which *can't* be solved using radicals which is why I can't give you an exact answer to this problem.

Comment: Oh okay,thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\frac{1}{2^6}*(x+k)^6(x-4)^6\\(x+k)^6(x-4)^6=(P(x)+15x^2k^4+6xk^5+k^6)(Q(x)+15x^2*4^4-6x*4^5+4^6)\\15*4^4*k^6-36*4^5*k^5+4^6*15k^4$$ We have isolated the coefficient of $x^2$ so we have $$15*4k^6-36*4^2k^5+15*4^3k^4=84$$ hence
$$5k^6-48k^5+80k^4=7$$
This equation is irreducible and Wolfram gives $$\color{red}{k\approx 0.603231}$$

Comment: Thanks for the other way to do the question!!!

Comment: You are welcome.